# Branding Sub-site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: css, branding, sub-site

I am trying to create custom UI for the sub site in SharePoint 2010. I am already using a custom master page at site collection level. I don't want that master page to be applied to my Sub-site. I want to create a separate css which could show my sub-site in different UI compared to Site level UI. Sub site has lot of pages which should be shown in navigation on the home page of sub site with good UI. I am looking for any guide or links which could help me in this.Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your own MasterPage & CSS for Subsite using below steps.

**To upload the alternate style file for subsite**:

1. Choose Site Actions→All Site Settings.
   The Master Page link appears in the Look and Feel section.
2. Open the Master Page settings by clicking the Master Page link.
   The Site Master Page Settings page opens. This page has three sections, Site Master Page, System Master Page, and Alternate CSS URL.

   [image]
3. In the Alternate CSS URL section, select the Specify a CSS File to Be Used by This Publishing Site and All Sites That Inherit from It radio button.
   The Browse button enables.
4. Copy/paste the path to your file in the field or click the Browse button to locate where you uploaded your CSS file in the Style library.
   If you click the Browse button, make sure you're in the correct folder by clicking the Style Library link on the left.
5. Select the file, if you clicked the Browse button, and then click OK.
   You return to the Site Master Page Settings page. The path to your alternate style sheet appears next to the Browse button.
6. (Optional) Select the Reset All Subsites to Inherit This Alternate CSS URL check box.
   If you want all the subsites under the site you're on to use these same alternate styles, select this check box. If you don’t want the child sites to inherit the styles, leave the check box blank.
7. Click OK.

Your alternate styles appear.

Comment: Hi Hardik, that will help me thnaks alot.. can you refer me to some links on how to change the CSS to get better look to my sub site, Am looking for any step to step guide on modifying my home page and navigation..could you hep me in providing some links which would take me to do this. Thanks

Comment: Please try this article...http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-branding-101-cascading-style-sheets

Comment: Look into it as well...http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/03/14/create-custom-css-and-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010-aspx/

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new master page for your sub site.
2. Upload master page to master page gallery.
3. Publish and Approve new master page.
4. Make sure publishing feature is enabled.
5. Open sub site change master page url (http://server/site/subsite/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx) and apply new master page to your sub site.